# Seeing modified dates of feature classes in geodatabases from ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, date, arccatalog

I would like to see the modified date of each layers in the geodatabases. For some reason I can't see them in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2. However, they appear under File explorer. As the layer are into geodatabases. It is impossible for me to relate with the layers name?

Is there a place in ArcGIS Desktop where the modified dates could be visible?

[image]

Comment: You can in ArcCatalog add the date modified field to its display in the Customize options and do the same for the Pro equivalent.  It will show layers and real dates modified for each.  Shapefiles are a dataset that aren't part of file geodatabases.  If stuck in a gdb folder they should be moved out.  Note file geodatabase as a whole dates aren't good because dates get updated every time a layer in them is accessed due to lock files being placed on it.

Comment: Good, I found it in ArcCatalog, under customize, ArcCatalog Options and Contents tab. Cheers John

Comment: Shapefiles can't be in geodatabases. Do you mean feature classes?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcGIS Pro then please do that in a separate question.